# T-SQL - Pass in a list of Ids to create ID Relational Table to New Record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

This is my first question on stack overflow, so please let me know if I can improve the context.

I want to create an Manufacturer Part Number record that has many to many relationships with Manufacturers. I have tried to pass in a list of manufacturer Ids along with the necessary info for creating the MPN. The IdList is just a TVP with Id INT as its only column.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMpns_Create]
    @Id int OUTPUT,
    @ManufacturerIdList IdList readonly,
    @Mpn nvarchar(25)
AS
begin
    insert into dbo.Mpns(Mpn)
    values (@Mpn);

    select @Id = @@IDENTITY;

    insert into dbo.Manufacturer_Mpn (ManufacturerId, MpnId)
    values((select Id from IdList), @Id)
end
```

Obviously this doesn't work for the last insert statement. How would I build a table based on the selected Id that inserts the multiple rows to the intermediary table that is Manufacturer_Mpn? My goal is to do with with one call to the database.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. DDL and sample data would help clarify your "list". Aside: You should do some reaesrch on `@@Identity` and better choices. [The Joys of @@IDENTITY, Scope_Identity and IDENT_CURRENT](https://sqlrambling.net/2017/03/31/the-joys-of-rowcount-scope_identity-and-ident_current/) is one of many resources.

Comment: I'm know it's a duplicate, I've answered such a question myself not so long ago, Just can't seem to find it.

Comment: itime itime itime atime itime nime nime nime nime nime ruhe ruhe ruhe ruhe stahe stahe stahe stuhe shuhe

Comment: @ZoharPeled I wasn't able to find a similar question, let me know if you end up digging it up so I can read that one too. Thanks :)

Comment: Basically, the same answer. Not worth the time to search it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into dbo.Manufacturer_Mpn (ManufacturerId, MpnId)
    select Id, @Id
    from @ManufacturerIdList;
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want:

```
insert into dbo.Manufacturer_Mpn (ManufacturerId, MpnId)
select Id, @Id from @ManufacturerIdList
```